Eth wallet activity tracking
I've been actively trying to track my eth wallet address, but unfortunately I couldn't find the solution. In solution I don't mean ethscan api and etc. Regardless of listening to all the block transactions, is there any way to track the ones that contain my wallet address? Or can I somehow listen to wallet it self for the upcoming updates?
Thank you in advance )

There are several Ethereum "portfolio tracking" dashboards where you can track anyone's address by just entering the address into the said service.

I'm trying to implement it by my own to then do some other stuff... I don't want to use already built platform...

Ethereum and other EVMs do not provide a generic mechanics to track activity of an wallet. This is a design flaw in EVM.
The only way to do it

Go through every block
Go through every transaction
Write an adapter for every DeFi protocol out there
Interpret everything in every transaction
Based on your heurestic, if you think this transaction is related to your own wallet then apply whatever changes within your in-house software

Naturally this is very difficult and only very well resourced software development teams can do it.
For certain extend you can track transactions from your wallet address, but this does not give all the information (not receiving ETH, changes in liquidity in protocols, and so on)
Also check the open source application Rotki that might give you a starting point with the code.

Thank you very much for the explanation, going through every block ain't going to be cheap. So is checking wallet holdings periodically(using intervals) a good idea/practice? Is it possible to just check the wallet holdings as a stale data?

That's the best you can do
